# New icons (4.2) do not display

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I've tried using several of the icons and at first noticed that while some displayed others did not, despite the only thing different was the icon name. I then tried this with lots of the icons and noticed that its only the icons listed as released since 4.2 that dont appear. All older ones show up no problem.

Any Idea whats going on?!

Comment: Er, what are we talking about here. What is 4.2?

Comment: I supose he is talking about fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well when using Font Awesome 4.2. I was using CodeKit to compile a number of Less source files into a single stylesheet. For some reason, the 4.2 icons weren't showing up. Strange.

Then I realized that the browser was pulling in an older copy of FontAwesome that I had installed locally on my system. Changing the `@import` statement to pull in the minified CSS worked. Hmmm...

Turned out that I needed to tell CodeKit to generate relative URLs, otherwise the web fonts had the wrong path causing them not to load. Here's how you can change that setting in CodeKit:

`[Select Project] > Settings > Languages > Less > [X] Generate relative URLs`

I'm not sure if you're using CodeKit as well, but I suspect you're trying to compile the source in some way and running into a similar problem.